# Power BI - using downloaded visuals

Tags: visualization, powerbi

So I downloaded some Visuals from the Power BI Visuals Gallery. I now have PBIVIZ files in my download folder.

According to the site of Power BI, I should be able upload them by using the upload button:

[image: Power BI screenshot]

but when I check my Power BI, I don't have such an option?

[image: My Power BI]

Did I forget something or does this work in another way?

EDIT: There is nothing under Menu -> Import neither.

Comment: What version of PowerBI are you running? File > About.

Comment: I see the "..." icon for importing in the latest version from the website, 2.28.4190.122

Comment: As suggested by Kyle, upgrade your Power BI.

Comment: Indeed, I have been using version 2.27.4163.351 (don't know why because I have downloaded it last week.), I will update it right now and report back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Appearently, as Kyle and Vasim have said, I was running an older version of Power BI. After a quick update, I was able to get the "..." icon.

Special thanks to Kyle and Vasim again.